# Is there possible duplicated triples in TDB2?

Tags: rdf, jena, tdb

I'm using Jena TDB2 and I loaded a TDB dataset.
I want to know whether TDB will contain two same triples or the loaded triples had been deduplicated when it build the TDB database.

Comment: no, it won't be duplicated

Comment: Answered: https://github.com/apache/jena/issues/1976

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the question:

> Is there possible duplicated triples in TDB2?

as been asked as an issue on the [Apache Jena Github](https://github.com/apache/jena/issues/1976), the answer is:

> An RDF graph is a set of triples - there are no duplicates in a graph.
>
> A triple can be in several graphs. If you use the union default graph feature (make the default graph for query be the union of all the named graphs), there will still only be one triple in the default graph.